# VB Script to test if a member is a group of a diferrent domain using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

Hi I am wondering if someone can help me figure out how to write a script that can check a username to see if it is in a specific active-directory group. The group however is in the parent domain, so we have a domain of say Midwest.Contoso.com and the user being "John Doe", I need to be able to run a query against the group top_level_admin that resides in just Contoso.com.

All of the scripts I have found seem to only run query's of the Midwest domain without seeing the group in the parent domain. I do not know enough about the ADO functionality within VBScript to get anything to work. Does anyone have a script they would be generous enough to share so that I can save a little time until I have learned more about VBScripting?

I would like to be able to just type the name of the group and a username to run the query against from on a machine but I have been messing with this for three days now and would just like to get something moving so I thought I would ask for some help.

here is the code I have been trying to make work for me as it accesses the parent domain like I need and gathers information about groups and users from the entire forest.

```
'Flush out all domain names found in AD and add them to arrDomainNames

        set objRootDSE   = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

        strBase          = "<LDAP://cn=Partitions," & objRootDSE.Get("ConfigurationNamingContext") & ">;"

        strFilter        = "(&(objectcategory=crossRef)(systemFlags=3));"

        strAttrs         = "name,trustParent,nCName,dnsRoot,distinguishedName;"

        strScope         = "onelevel"

        set objConn      = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        objConn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"

        objConn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

        set objRS = objConn.Execute(strBase & strFilter & strAttrs & strScope)

        objRS.MoveFirst


        set arrDomainNames     = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        set dicDomainHierarchy = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        set dicDomainRoot      = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


        while not objRS.EOF 

            dicDomainRoot.Add objRS.Fields("name").Value, objRS.Fields("nCName").Value

                if objRS.Fields("trustParent").Value <> "" then

                    arrDomainNames.Add objRS.Fields("name").Value, 0

                    set objDomainParent = GetObject("LDAP://" & objRS.Fields("trustParent").Value)

                    dicDomainHierarchy.Add objRS.Fields("name").Value,objDomainParent.Get("name")

               else 

                    arrDomainNames.Add objRS.Fields("name").Value, 1

               end if

               objRS.MoveNext

        wend


        'Attach to Active Directory

        Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

        Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"

        adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

        adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection


        for each strDomain in arrDomainNames

            strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDomain & ">"

            strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group))"

            strAttributes = "name,cn,member"

            strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"

            adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery

            adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100

            adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30

            adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

            adoCommand.Properties("Sort On") = "cn"

            Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute

            inNumGroups = 0

            Wscript.Echo ("Pre-Processing " & strFilter & " Data...")

            '===Write information to Export File===

            While Not adoRecordset.EOF

                'working code

                arrMember = adoRecordset.Fields("member")

                if IsArray(arrmember) then

                    For each strMember in arrMember

                        'workingcode

                        msgbox adoRecordset.Fields("cn") & vbCRLF & strMember

                    Next

                else

                    msgbox adoRecordset.Fields("cn") & vbCRLF & "This group has no members"

                end if

                adoRecordset.MoveNext

            wend

        Next
```

Comment: Before we deep dive into your code - since you want to access AD via LDAP - make sure you can see required user and his groups using LDAP Browser http://www.ldapadministrator.com (or your favorite tool). It should help to understand what you look for and how your AD is setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that I ended up with, But thank you for your help!

```
strGroupDN = "CN=UserGroup,OU=MainOU,OU=SecondaryGroup,OU=MainGroups,DC=Primary,DC=FQDN,DC=com"
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & strGroupDN)

‘wscript.echo strGroupDN

‘Uncomment the following three lines to have the system check the current users directory information rather than specifically specifying the user like it currently is below.
'Set objADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
' strUserDN will look like CN=TestUser1,OU=End Users,CN=UserGroup,OU=MainOU,OU=SecondaryGroup,OU=MainGroups,DC=Primary,DC=FQDN,DC=com
'strUserDN = objADSysInfo.UserName


strUserDn = "CN=TestUser1,OU=End Users,CN=UserGroup,OU=MainOU,OU=SecondaryGroup,OU=MainGroups,DC=Primary,DC=FQDN,DC=com"
‘wscript.echo strUserDN
If objGroup.IsMember("LDAP://" & strUserDN) Then
    wscript.echo "The User is in the group"
  ' The user is in the group so run the following actions

    else

    wscript.echo "The user is not in the group"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you can start with

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strDomain = objNetwork.UserDomain
strUser = objNetwork.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomain & "/" & strUser)

Dim groups
For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
    groups = groups & objGroup.Name & vbCRLF
Next

MsgBox groups
```

If expected group is not shown, make sure you see it using ADSI editor or LDAP browser.

Comment: Although I do like the simplicity of that script, that only accesses the current domain that I am logged into. By default I am logged into midwest.contoso.com as my domain, but there is a special set of groups located within the parent domain of contoso.com. This will only output the groups that I am a member of within the midwest.contoso.com

Comment: I went ahead and attached some of the code I have been working on to try and get things going. But like I said I just do not know enough about VB Scripting to work with the ADB Objects like I believe I need. I could be entirely wrong and going a very long route to get what I need so if you know how to make it work or an easier way to get the information out of the parent directory of active directory please feel free to share.

Comment: Now the code I attached also currently pulls every group for every user within the entire forest, which is fine but I would need a way to filter out the results to do some checking against the group name and user that I specifically want to check. Then after it checks to see if either the user is or is not a member to display a message box based on those results.

Comment: What happen if you set required domain in `strDomain`? The example above takes the domain of the current user. Also I think if there is a trust between both domains you should see all groups, if there is no trust then you might need to login to the required domain before you query it.